# Es posible obtener dos resultados(sum) independientes de una sola consulta en LINQ?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy modificando un programa y quiero obtener dos sumas independientemente del id y guardarlas en variables independientes una de otra. También me serviría obtener una tabla resultante de una linea con solo las dos columnas sumadas.

Con esta tabla de ejemplo.

```
+----+--------+-----------------+
| id | sueldo | propiedades(m2) |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|  1 |   1000 |             400 |
|  2 |   1500 |             200 |
|  3 |   2000 |             300 |
+----+--------+-----------------+



 sueldototal, propiedadestotal = (from...where..select)
```

o

```
dim z = (....select sum(sueldo), sum(propiedades))
```

resultado(z):

```
+--------+-----------------+
| sueldo | propiedades(m2) |
+--------+-----------------+
|   4500 |             900 |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Sería interesante que mostraras si has intentado algo. Otro detalle, estas programando en C# o VB.NET?

Comment: No había visto que habias editado tu pregunta. Asumo que tus datos estan en un `DataTable`, es asi? Si es asi, hay varias formas de hacerlo, puedes crear una tupla, o una clase anónima, o crear un datatable nuevo.

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo en vb.net. Si no es algo sencillo no creo que me sirva. Probare de crear una tupla que parece mas sencillo. Gracias :)

Comment: Te voy a añadir un ejemplo creando una clase anónima, a ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una clase anónima para tener los datos categorizados en una nueva clase. Sería algo asi:

```
Dim resSuma = New With {Key
  .sueldo = dt1.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("sueldo")), Key
  .propiedades = dt1.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("propiedades"))
  }
```

Para acceder a los resultados, simplemente debes poner `resSuma.Sueldo` y `resSuma.propiedades`.